# Authorizing your own google account in django using oauth2

Tags: python, django, oauth-2.0

I am trying to set up a django app which needs access to my own (not a user's) google calendar. I'd rather not have to go through the whole oauth process just to do this, so I set up my authentication in a file (called calendar.dat) in the same directory as the django view which uses my calendar. The code to authorize my account is as follows:

```
import os.path
import httplib2
from oauth2client.file import Storage

module_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
file_path = os.path.join(module_dir, 'calendar.dat')
storage = Storage(file_path)
credentials = storage.get()

http = hhtplib2.Http()
http = credentials.authorize(http)
```

When this code runs through a call from the browser I get the error that credentials = None. However, if I put this code in a normal python file in the same directory and just run it in the terminal it works. Is there something about django that is messing this up and is there a way I can fix this? Somewhat of a beginner, sorry if this is a novice question.